# Rvm on beagleboneblack disable posix

Tags: rvm, angstrom-linux, beagleboneblack

I'm trying to run rvm on Angstrom linux on BBB.

When i try to launch rvm, i obtain:

RVM can not be run with `set -o posix`, please turn it off and try again.

Someone know about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a check to prevent running RVM from pure **Sh** shells, for proper functioning RVM requires **Arrays**(along other features) which are only available in **Bash** and **Zsh**.

Answer (score 0):

Answer shared by @mapapis was useful to understand the reason (thanks) but I think precise steps to change the default login shell complement this and are useful.

As stated [here](http://www.ur-ban.com/2013/06/20/rvm-can-not-be-run-with-set-o-posix/) you may need to change the login shell for your user in order to use the shell of your preference by default, in my case is `bash` so I made some changes the way I launch my terminal.

`chsh` is advised but in my particular case I'm using [ConEmu Windows Terminal](https://conemu.github.io/) with [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/) in a Windows 10 environment; `sh.exe` is used by default thus this RVM warning...
`chsh` is not available in Cygwin, so I followed [this reccomendation](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2010-09/msg00119.html) that states that:

> it is just a matter of changing (...) whatever shortcut you
>   are using to start cygwin to call {prefered shell here} instead

I hope this is useful. Gretings!