# ruby manager RVM complaining about posix

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

I just got this message when I run `rvm get`

```
RVM can not be run with `set -o posix`, please turn it off and try again.
```

This could also be the reason why it can't find Guard template files.

What does it mean, and how can I solve this?

thanks inadv

Comment: See if this answer is suitable, for me it was :)

http://stackoverflow.com/a/19186315/2677943

Answer (score 0):

Question/answer shared by @swenzel was useful to understand the reason (thanks) but I think precise steps to overcome this warning are needed.

As stated [here](http://www.ur-ban.com/2013/06/20/rvm-can-not-be-run-with-set-o-posix/) you may need to change the login shell for your user in order to use the shell of your preference by default, in my case is `bash` so I made some changes the way I launch my terminal.

`chsh` is advised but in my particular case I'm using [ConEmu Windows Terminal](https://conemu.github.io/) with [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/) in a Windows 10 environment; `sh.exe` is used by default thus this RVM warning...
`chsh` is not available in Cygwin, so I followed [this reccomendation](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2010-09/msg00119.html) that states that:

> it is just a matter of changing (...) whatever shortcut you
>   are using to start cygwin to call {prefered shell here} instead

I hope this is useful. Gretings!